# What is tensorflow.Summary used for?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am confused about `tensorflow.Summary` class.

I found the following piece of code as part of `tensorflow.models.textsum.seq2seq_attention._RunningAvgLoss` function

```
loss_sum = tf.Summary()  
loss_sum.value.add(tag='running_avg_loss', simple_value=running_avg_loss)
```

what dose `Summary()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tf.Summary class is used to export information about a model. You can use it for example to display information about the training process using [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard).

In the [TensorFlow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics) you can find a tutorial about the usage of TensorBoard.